# Z-Index question: div on top of canvas using z-index is not working

Tags: html, css

Currently I have the following:

```html
<canvas id="backgroundCanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; display: inline;" width="950" height="1600"></canvas>
    
    <div id="dmsInsWorkArea" class="dmsInsWorkArea">
       <iframe name="rightSide">...</iframe>
       <div name="leftSide" id="dmsInlineCommentsDiv" style="margin-left:70%;z-index: 10;">
          <div name="dmsCommentBox:45" style="border-radius: 11px; width: auto; z-index: 10; border: 1px solid grey;"></div>
          <div name="dmsCommentBox:46" style="border-radius: 11px; width: auto; z-index: 10; border: 1px solid grey;"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Currently the canvas is on top of everything.
However, I would like to canvas to be on top of the rightSide, but below left leftSide.
Any idea how to do this? Changing the z-index of leftSide does not seems to work.

Image:
https://ibb.co/3YGb673

Comment: `position: absolute` need to  `position: relative ;`  to it's parent ..

Comment: please be specific about the problem so we can help you.

Comment: `z-index` is relative to its parent. Your `rightSide` and `leftSide` are in the same parent element, so you won't be able make the `rightSide` go behind the canvas element.